# How can I merge files into 1 file, and how to split them after the merge

Tags: .net, vb.net, merge, resources, game-development

I am building a game, the game need to load resources like photos and text files.

now let's say that for every level the game has to load new resources.

I want to merge files (photos + text) and it will be a resource file, and my game we know how to open this file and separate the files, and then read them.

Demonstration :

[image]

So how to I do it (I want that my game will be able to merge and separate files)?

Comment: VB.NET <> VB6. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can preserve the fixed length of byte array in your custom file to store the start position and end position of both files in that byte array. for example if you have consumed the index 0 to 19 in the custom file byte data to store the information like `Image:21,3520;Text:3521,6550`. then you can easily split that array again after merging file in a sequence by retrieving information from that fixed byte location. This is the simplest way to do this.

```
Image File Length: 12000

Text File Length: 500
```

then your new array will be created like

```
byte[] data = new byte[12000 + 500 + 20];
```

in that array you need to store information about both file location in 0 to 19 index. (You can increase it as your needs).

```
//Information
data[0] = ...
data[19] = ...

//Image file
data[20] = ...
data[12019] = ...

//Text file
data[12020] = ...
data[12519] = ...
```

then write that byte array into file using `System.IO.WriteAllBytes()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a resource file like the ones Visual Basic uses, I don't think they actually contain the images...

If it's your own file, I recommend using the [ZipFile Class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) for .net 3.0, 3.5

For .net 4.5, 4.6 `ZipFile Class`, like Vincet wrote.